# Insert file content after a specified string in file with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following file:

mongo

```
    'mongodb' => [
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'options'  => [
            'database' => 'admin' // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
        ]
    ],
```

and the sed command:

```
sed -i "/'connections' => \[/a \ "$(cat mongo)" \\" /app/config/database.php
```

So I want to insert the content of `mongo` file after the string:

```
'connections' => [
```

The search is good, sed founds the string, but does not get properly the content of the file `mongo`.

I get the following errors:

```
sed: can't read 'mongodb': No such file or directory
sed: can't read =>: No such file or directory
sed: can't read [: No such file or directory
sed: can't read 'driver': No such file or directory
sed: can't read =>: No such file or directory
sed: can't read 'mongodb',: No such file or directory
sed: can't read 'host': No such file or directory
```

Comment: This looks like the output from php's `var_dump()`. Right?

Comment: Something like ... is an array with a configuration that I want to insert into a config php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -i '/'\''connections'\'' => \[/r mongoFile' file
```

Read the mongoFile in after the `connections` address.